# Make android activity close itelf

Tags: java, android

I have a function time() in my openGLActivity class. The openGLActivity is open by my Main activtiy. I've tried calling super.onPause() then super.onStop(); and i just get errors. This time function is called inside of my GLrenderer class. Can an activity cloe itself after a time limit?

```
timer(){
t+=1;
     if(t==1000){
       finish();
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display an activity automatically after 5 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304035/how-to-display-an-activity-automatically-after-5-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, you can easily do that with handler. This should close the activity. Use it onCreate()

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        OpenGLActivity.this.finish();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. It means that if Activity1 calls Acitivity2  by

```
startActivity(Intent i)
```

Activity2 remains alive until you go back since the Activity1.