# Black Screen Shows in Android ( Splash Screen )

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

**What is Problem ?**

My app is social forum app. When i try to login app. After splash screen it shows black screen. How Can I Resolve this ?

**What you have tried ?**

1. when i try it on emulator. it sometimes work but if i try to logout and login. black screen comes.
2. i changed sleep time(8000-9000-10000). it sometimes work but when i try to login with username and password black screen comes.
3. there is no error in debug mode and i checked ftp logs too.
4. i tried alternative solutions on internet but it didn't work.

**Here is my splash activity**

```
package com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.abulletin.forumapp.R;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        getActionBar().hide();

        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Here is my manifest xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abulletin.forumapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mymonas.ngobrol.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.MyApplication"
        android:logo="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Blue" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.util.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.mymonas.ngobrol.services" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.util.GCMNotificationReceiver" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.PostActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_post" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.ProfileActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.CategoryThreadActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.AddEditThreadActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.EditProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/profile_menu_edit" >
        </activity>

       <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            android:value="0ab64bea47ca3f35dffbd2c94200fbc26be26009" /> -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.abulletin.forumapp.Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="aBulletin Android Forum"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are calling `finish()` in the `onPause` method?

Comment: same reason for here; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle) I am just learning anroid programing. 
Where did I go wrong you think ?

Comment: I think you may be confused. You shouldnt call `finish()` in the `onPause` method.

Comment: Also it is pretty inadvisable to sleep threads. You should use something like a `Handler` and then call `postDelayed` on it. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304035/how-to-display-an-activity-automatically-after-5-seconds

Comment: İ am tired to try. Problem is still existing.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while when you ask the question but maybe it can help for someone. The problem is because of the image that you want to use for splash screen. Maybe you can see on android Monitor in android studio there is an error like ;

```
07-18 23:21:02.646 23482-23523/com.example.arslan.appphone W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2880x5120, max=4096x4096)
```

This is the main problem. Android can't running splash screen with that large image.